# New customer groups - which settings do I need to update to use these groups?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, customer-group

Last week I created new customer groups because I installed an extension that needed them. Today I found out that a shopping cart price rule didn't work. It turned out that price rules are linked to customer groups, and I didn't change the price rule for the new customer groups.

I solved this problem, but this made me think: what else uses customer groups that will not work anymore now I use those new groups?

Comment: Taxes, tier prices

Comment: This new extension is about tax, and that is covered. We don't use tier prices, but good to know!

Comment: I forgot **catalog price rules**. You mentioned shopping cart price rules and I thought they were covered also, but they weren't

Comment: You're right, but we don't use them either. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following things have links to customer group:

1. Catalog rules,
2. Tier prices,
3. Bundle prices,
4. Bundle options,
5. Product Prices,
6. Configurable options and prices,
7. Sales rules,
8. Taxes including weee,

One thing to note is that all this information will update and delete according to customer groups because of foreign keys, obviously as noted new groups would have to set-up everything as new.